# MySQL issue at boot time

Tags: mysql, linux, permissions, boot, tcp

can you help me?

I got this error when service mysqld_multi starts on boot:

> 161118 13:18:57 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from
>   /var/lib/mysql/monitor
>
> 161118 13:18:58 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.48-MariaDB)
>   starting as process 3076 ...
>
> 161118 13:18:58 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
>
> 161118 13:18:58 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>
> 161118 13:18:58 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
>
> 161118 13:18:58 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
>
> 161118 13:18:58 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>
> 161118 13:18:58 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
>
> 161118 13:18:58  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
>
> 161118 13:18:59 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com)
>   5.5.47-MariaDB-37.7  started; log sequence number 7008339
>
> 161118 13:18:59 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>
> 161118 13:18:59 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
>
> 161118 13:18:59 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
>
> 161118 13:18:59 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got
>   error: 13: Permission denied
>
> 161118 13:18:59 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server
>   running on port: 13306 ?
>
> 161118 13:18:59 [ERROR] Aborting
>
> 161118 13:18:59  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
>
> 161118 13:19:00  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number
>   7008339
>
> 161118 13:19:00 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
>
> 161118 13:19:00 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file 
>   /var/lib/mysql/monitor/mysqld002.pid ended
>
> Once the server is up if I do "service mysqld_multi start" as root
>   user I get this  output and MYSQL begin to work:
>
> 161118 13:25:11 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from
>   /var/lib/mysql/monitor
>
> 161118 13:25:11 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.48-MariaDB)
>   starting as process 3876 ...
>
> 161118 13:25:11 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
>
> 161118 13:25:11 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>
> 161118 13:25:11 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
>
> 161118 13:25:11 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
>
> 161118 13:25:11 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>
> 161118 13:25:11 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
>
> 161118 13:25:11  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
>
> 161118 13:25:12 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com)
>   5.5.47-MariaDB-37.7 started; log sequence number 7008339
>
> 161118 13:25:12 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>
> 161118 13:25:12 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
>
> 161118 13:25:12 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
>
> 161118 13:25:12 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
>
> 161118 13:25:12 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
>
> Version: '5.5.48-MariaDB'  socket:
>   '/var/lib/mysql/monitor/mysqld002.sock'  port: 13306  MariaDB Server

WHY????????

Comment: You're using mysqld_multi - Have you checked that you are not starting mysqld on boot as well? Also, what's in your configuration file?

Comment: Hi, mysqld service is disable an deleted in chkconfig. It was the first thing that i thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem SOLVED.

The problem was the state of SELinux.
Changing the parameter SELINUX to "permissive" instead of "enforcing" (in the file /etc/sysconfig/selinux) the service starts OK at boot time.

That's all.